# AddHandler Lambda Expression

Tags: wpf, vb.net, lambda, expression

The code:

```
    Dim x, y as [Delegate]
    x = Sub() MeMouseMove(points)
    y = Sub() MeMouseDown(points)
    AddHandler MainGrid.MouseMove, x
    AddHandler MainGrid.MouseLeftButtonDown, y
```

Code background:

- 'MainGrid' is a grid that is the same size and width as the window it is in
- 'x' and 'y' are declared as [Delegate]
- 'points' is a class I need to pass through the programmatically created handler
- 'MeMouseMove' and 'MeMouseDown' are subs that I need to call

The problem:

I get an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
>   Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'VB$AnonymousDelegate_0' to type 'System.Windows.Input.MouseEventHandler'.

**I believe the problem is with the declaration of the x and y variables**

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks for the time, Red

Comment: A MouseEventHandler has two arguments, your lamda does not.

Comment: @HansPassant That doesn't work (see bonyjoe's answer below)

Comment: Tried: changing variable type to nothing (eg: "Dim x,y").  Same problem as initial

Comment: Bump.  Need help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution

```
        Dim x As New MouseEventHandler(Sub() MeMouseMove(points))
        Dim y As New MouseButtonEventHandler(Sub() MeMouseDown(points))
```

Changed variables 'x' and 'y' to proper variable types (not [Delegate])

Answer (score 1):

MouseEventHandler has two parameters Object sender and RoutedEventArgs e, so you should try

```
x = Sub(s, e) MeMouseMove(points)
y = Sub(s, e) MeMouseDown(points)
AddHandler MainGrid.MouseMove, AddressOf x
AddHandler MainGrid.MouseLeftButtonDown, AddressOf y
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that gives the same problem.  But thanks for the reply, it's always appreciated

Comment: Try now with the edit, I always forget you need the AddressOf operator in VB

Comment: Address Of does not work due to: 'AddressOf' operand must be the name of a method (without parentheses). Thanks for the help, Red

Comment: Ah ok, well one last try then. Replace the (s, e) with (sender As Object, e As EventArgs) and lose the AddressOf operators

Comment: Unfortunately, it gives the same error as initially.  I think the problem is with how I am declaring the variables 'x' and 'y' and not the expressions themselves

Comment: If you just declare the anonymous method directly in the addhandler call does it work? AddHandler MainGrid.MouseMove, Sub(......

Comment: That works but I need the lambda expressions individually so I can then remove the handler (and therefore delete the now "global" 'points' variable so that it doesn't stay in the memory.